# Can I use POST instead of PUT in a NodeJS app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, post, cassandra, put

What is the difference if I always use `POST` method to update a row in the MySQL or Cassandra database instead of `PUT`?

I ask this because when I did research on that I read in some other questions that were saying `POST` request causes multiple instances creation. I wanted to make sure if is that correct?

Comment: POST and PUT are http methods that are sent to your web application. This has nothing to do with your database. However, for restful applications, POST requests will generally do INSERT operations in your database while PUT and PATCH will UPDATE rows.

Answer (score 4):

The database doesn't care about how the server talks to clients.

Technically you could use **POST** for everything. That's basically how GraphQL works. But doing that means your API is not **RESTful**.

These are the basic RESTful API methods:

| Method | Description |
| --- | --- |
| GET | Retrieve information about the REST API resource |
| POST | Create a REST API resource |
| PUT | Update a REST API resource |
| DELETE | Delete a REST API resource or related component |

That being said, if you feel like your use-case works and reads better with just POST or GET, go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Neither mysql nor Cassandra will even be aware if the client made a http put or post request, so from a database point of view it is totally irrelevant which http request type you use.